# How can I manage to bake this out?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texture-baking

So the objective is to get it to look like this:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8urd4cazzo7dcu/Rendered.png?dl=1]

Blend file http://pasteall.org/blend/34831

I'm using cycles render for the material and I want to bake it out so it looks like it does in the render above. The black material bakes out fine with combined as a setting; however, the metal material will not seem to bake out properly no matter the setting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the glossy metal material will appear different from different camera angles. So it's impossible to bake it to a single static image and have it look like it should from any given camera angle.

There was [a patch](https://developer.blender.org/T40375) which allowed for glossy materials to be baked as if they were being viewed from a single pre-defined point, however it was removed from master shortly after it was added.

Comment: Ahg, that's unfortunate. The game that I'm making this for doesn't allow materials. It only allows the use of a texture. Guess I have to go back to the old method and just make it in an image editor.

I don't suppose you know how to get an effect like it quickly? ^^;